# React Native : clean Useeffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, expo

I ma facing this issue

**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

```
  useEffect(() => {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user !== null) {
        return firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((documentSnapshot) => {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
              setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
              setisloadingComplet(true);
            }
          });
      }
    });

    
  }, []);
```

when ever the user update his info . It does not update immediately until I refresh the app . and it throws me the warning above

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58565905/13410760

Comment: thanks ! I have just tried it but it did not work

Comment: hey ! => https://stackoverflow.com/a/67055689/11754047

Comment: @houcinolmostaf Besides unregistering firebase listeners in the cleanup you should check if the component is [still mounted](https://usehooks-typescript.com/react-hook/use-is-mounted) before setting state.

Comment: can you provide me with an example please

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys . I solved this .
the problem is that I get the data from both profile and homescreen.
what I did is removed getting the data from profile screen.
instead I got the user Data only from homescreen then pass it to profile screen via navigation.